# Query position of sign in Vim with sign ID

Tags: vim

I want to query Vim for the line number of a sign. I know the ID of the sign, as I was the one who placed it using `sign place {id}...`, but I want to be able to ask Vim for it's current position (as the user could edit the file and cause the sign to move).

I know that I can use `:sign place` to list all signs as so:

```
:sign place
--- Signs ---
Signs for plugin/python/vdebug/breakpoint.py:
    line=199  id=11000  name=breakpt
Signs for plugin/python/vdebug/event.py:
    line=9  id=11001  name=breakpt
```

But I then have to parse the output to find a single breakpoint by ID, which isn't very efficient, especially as there could be a very large number of signs. Is there a command or vimL function to get the attributes of a sign by the ID alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't any function (see `:help function-list`), thus parsing is the only option so far. I agree that having programmatic access would be beneficial; you may want to raise this enhancement request on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).

Edit: After [raising this on vim_dev](https://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/93f364b6734c0a4f), Christian Brabandt kindly has written a patch that lets you query the line number of a sign with id 42 through `line('|42')`. Let's hope Bram includes this in Vim soon.