# Capture output of vim command in Python

Tags: python, vim

I want to capture the output of a Vim command (`:sign place`), scripting in Python with the vim module.

I can execute commands with `vim.command(...)`, but this doesn't return the output of the command. I can evaluate vimL commands with `vim.eval(...)`, but this only works for variables and *functions*, not commands.

The only way I could capture the output of this command was to redirect to a register and then evaluate the contents of the register:

```
vim.command('redir @a')
vim.command('silent sign place')
vim.command('redir END')
command_output = vim.eval('@a')
```

But this seems like a lot of work for an apparently simple task. Is there a better way of doing this?

**Note:** this is not a question specific to the example command, `sign place` - it's valid for any command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no better way of capturing the output of a Vim command from a Python script, apart from redirecting (to a variable or buffer) and then evaluating the contents of that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's little support for signs in Vimscript yet (as per my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14503016/813602)). What I would do is write a Vimscript wrapper function around the `:redir` and `:sign`, and `vim.eval()` that from Python. In that wrapper, you can `:redir => var` to a local variable so that you don't clobber the register.

Comment: Thanks, but my question wasn't specifically related to signs. That's the command I'm using, but it could be any command. Also, redirecting to a variable works and is fine, but it's not any simpler or more concise.

Comment: The trick is to write that small wrapper function once and then use it everywhere from Python. I'm afraid that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13881/10254 might be of interest, basically **get input, then run command, capture and put**. Though in vimscript functions, not python,  `Capture(excmd)` `PutAfterCapture(command)` `GetInputCommandThenCaptureAndPut()`

excerpt:

```
func!  abort  " from tpope's scriptease.vim
try
    redir => out
    exe 'silent! '.a:excmd
finally
    redir END
endtry
return out
endfunc
```